# What is the length, width, and area of The Sandbox create mode grid?

Tags: the-sandbox

In the mobile game [The Sandbox](http://www.pixowl.com/games/the-sandbox/#) (not the sandbox evolution) I want to create a world but I need to know the amount of pixels on each side and how many pixels make up the grid (it's a retro style game). I've searched Google, and since it's a dead game all that pops up is stuff about The Sandbox Evolution or other games.

Comment: I would create a tag for you, but a web search for "The Sandbox Game" gives me multiple different results. Can you be more specific about which one you mean?

Comment: if you search "The sandbox pixowl" (pixowl because they made the game) there will be a sidebar with information. make sure you dont get confused with the sandbox evolution. thank you!

Comment: it seems like The-Sandbox is appropriate for the tag name.  I linked the games site in your question as well to help clarify.